Get updated values for nested fields in Firestore document
I am trying to implement a trigger (as a google cloud function)  in golang that gets invoked when a firestore document is updated. I am following the documentation give here:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore
My firestore document is given below:
{
  "aaBool": true,
  "aaInt": 1111,
  "aaStr": "Lorem",
  "map1": {
    "m1book": true,
    "m1int": 3333,
    "m1str": "m1Lorem"
  },
  "map2": {
    "map3": {
      "m3int": 888,
      "m3str": "m3Lorem"
    }
  }
}

The code I have currently is:
// Package trigger_firestore gets fired whenever any insert/update event occurs in the default firestore database.
package trigger_firestore

import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    _ "encoding/json"
    firebase "firebase.google.com/go/v4"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"
    "github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/v2/event"
    "github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents-go/cloud/firestoredata"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "google.golang.org/protobuf/proto"
    "log"
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
)

// set the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT environment variable when deploying.
var (
    projectID = os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT")
)

// client is a Firestore client, reused between function invocations.
var client *firestore.Client

func init() {
    // Use the application default credentials.
    conf := &firebase.Config{ProjectID: projectID}

    // Use context.Background() because the app/client should persist across
    // invocations.
    ctx := context.Background()

    app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("firebase.NewApp: %v", err)
    }

    client, err = app.Firestore(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("app.Firestore: %v", err)
    }

    // Register cloud event function
    functions.CloudEvent("ProcessTrigger", ProcessTrigger)
}

func ProcessTrigger(ctx context.Context, event event.Event) error {

    var data firestoredata.DocumentEventData
    if err := proto.Unmarshal(event.Data(), &data); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("proto.Unmarshal: %w", err)
    }

    fullPath := strings.Split(data.GetValue().GetName(), "/documents/")[1]
    pathParts := strings.Split(fullPath, "/")
    doc := strings.Join(pathParts[1:], "/")
    log.Printf("Doc: %+v\n", doc)

    log.Printf("Function triggered by change to: %v\n", event.Source())
    log.Printf("Old value: %+v\n", data.GetOldValue())
    log.Printf("New value: %+v\n", data.GetValue())

    processUpdate(&data)

    return nil

}

func processUpdate(data *firestoredata.DocumentEventData) {
    updateMask := data.GetUpdateMask()
    log.Printf("Update Mask: %+v\n", updateMask)

    for _, fieldName := range updateMask.GetFieldPaths() {
        log.Printf("=================================")
        log.Printf("FieldName: %v", fieldName)
        log.Printf("FieldNameType: %v", reflect.TypeOf(fieldName))

        fieldValue, ok := data.GetValue().GetFields()[fieldName]
        if ok {
            log.Printf("FieldValue: %v", fieldValue)
            stringSlice := strings.Split(fieldValue.String(), ":")
            log.Println(stringSlice)
        }
    }
}


The above code works fine for updates to the top-level non-nested-fields (prefix aa) and I am able to print the fieldValue.
However for updates to nested fields (inside map1 and map3), ok is false.
How do I get the updated fieldValue for nested fields?
The logs generated are:
2024/04/14 14:55:44 Doc: testdoc
2024/04/14 14:55:44 Function triggered by change to: //firestore.googleapis.com/projects/myproj/databases/(default)
2024/04/14 14:55:44 Old value: name:"projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/testcollection/testdoc" fields:{key:"aaBool" value:{boolean_value:true}} fields:{key:"aaInt" value:{integer_value:11111}} fields:{key:"aaStr" value:{string_value:"Lorem"}} fields:{key:"map1" value:{map_value:{fields:{key:"m1book" value:{boolean_value:true}} fields:{key:"m1int" value:{integer_value:3333}} fields:{key:"m1str" value:{string_value:"m1Lorem"}}}}} fields:{key:"map2" value:{map_value:{fields:{key:"map3" value:{map_value:{fields:{key:"m3int" value:{integer_value:888}} fields:{key:"m3str" value:{string_value:"m3Lorem"}}}}}}}} create_time:{seconds:1713104864 nanos:548214000} update_time:{seconds:1713106076 nanos:80031000}
2024/04/14 14:55:44 New value: name:"projects/myproj/databases/(default)/documents/testcollection/testdoc" fields:{key:"aaBool" value:{boolean_value:false}} fields:{key:"aaInt" value:{integer_value:222}} fields:{key:"aaStr" value:{string_value:"LoremIpsum"}} fields:{key:"map1" value:{map_value:{fields:{key:"m1book" value:{boolean_value:false}} fields:{key:"m1int" value:{integer_value:4444}} fields:{key:"m1str" value:{string_value:"m1LoremIpsum"}}}}} fields:{key:"map2" value:{map_value:{fields:{key:"map3" value:{map_value:{fields:{key:"m3int" value:{integer_value:999}} fields:{key:"m3str" value:{string_value:"m3LoremIpsum"}}}}}}}} create_time:{seconds:1713104864 nanos:548214000} update_time:{seconds:1713106543 nanos:26415000}
2024/04/14 14:55:44 Update Mask: field_paths:"map2.map3.m3int" field_paths:"map2.map3.m3str" field_paths:"map1.m1str" field_paths:"map1.m1int" field_paths:"map1.m1book" field_paths:"aaStr" field_paths:"aaBool" field_paths:"aaInt"
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: map2.map3.m3int
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: map2.map3.m3str
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: map1.m1str
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: map1.m1int
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: map1.m1book
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: aaStr
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldValue: string_value:"LoremIpsum"
2024/04/14 14:55:44 [string_value "LoremIpsum"]
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: aaBool
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldValue: boolean_value:false
2024/04/14 14:55:44 [boolean_value false]
2024/04/14 14:55:44 =================================
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldName: aaInt
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldNameType: string
2024/04/14 14:55:44 FieldValue: integer_value:222
2024/04/14 14:55:44 [integer_value 222]


In case required, this is how I deploy the trigger:
gcloud functions deploy test-trigger-1 \
    --gen2 \
    --runtime=go122 \
    --region=us-west1 \
    --trigger-location=us-west1 \
    --source=. \
    --entry-point=ProcessTrigger \
    --min-instances=1 \
    --memory=256Mi \
    --set-env-vars=[GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=myproj] \
    --trigger-event-filters=type=google.cloud.firestore.document.v1.written \
    --trigger-event-filters=database='(default)' \
    --trigger-event-filters-path-pattern=document='testcollection/{docID}'


It would be more helpful if you show actual document content and the output of all of the logging statements that show how this code runs.  I'm having a hard time following what you have now.  Your question should contain enough information that anyone can use to duplicate the results.

Have provided all the details.. -Thanks

The relevant logs should be pasted into the question itself. Don't provide links - they might not be around and helpful for others later.

Have put logs inline, thanks

From the discussion here, it seems that Google has not provided any straightforward way to access the nested fields, and has no inclination of doing so. Out of sheer frustration, some individual contributors on this discussion thread have implemented and posted solutions. I tested one of them and it worked. Am pasting this solution below. Will use it until I find something better.

func parseFirestoreDocument(value *firestoredata.Document) map[string]interface{} {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }

    fields := value.GetFields()

    if fields == nil {
        return nil
    }

    result := make(map[string]interface{})

    for k, v := range fields {
        result[k] = parseValue(v)
    }

    return result
}

func parseValue(value *firestoredata.Value) interface{} {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }

    switch value.ValueType.(type) {
    case *firestoredata.Value_NullValue:
        return nil
    case *firestoredata.Value_BooleanValue:
        return value.GetBooleanValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_IntegerValue:
        return value.GetIntegerValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_DoubleValue:
        return value.GetDoubleValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_StringValue:
        return value.GetStringValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_TimestampValue:
        return value.GetTimestampValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_GeoPointValue:
        return value.GetGeoPointValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_BytesValue:
        return value.GetBytesValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_ReferenceValue:
        return value.GetReferenceValue()
    case *firestoredata.Value_ArrayValue:
        return parseArray(value.GetArrayValue())
    case *firestoredata.Value_MapValue:
        return parseMap(value.GetMapValue())
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

func parseMap(value *firestoredata.MapValue) interface{} {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }

    fields := value.GetFields()

    if fields == nil {
        return nil
    }

    result := make(map[string]interface{})

    for k, v := range fields {
        result[k] = parseValue(v)
    }

    return result
}

func parseArray(value *firestoredata.ArrayValue) interface{} {
    if value == nil {
        return nil
    }

    values := value.GetValues()

    if values == nil {
        return nil
    }

    result := make([]interface{}, len(values))

    for i, v := range values {
        result[i] = parseValue(v)
    }

    return result
}


I use this and it works for deeply nested fields too. Since the firebase types are limited, we can easily switch and parse them recursively as needed.

Taken from: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1438
